# Slider image not responsive - EventsAir website

Tags: css, image, slider

I am building an event website on the event management platform EventsAir.  I am trying to use their content block that includes an image slider on the left and a text box on the right.  I have been in contact with their tech support because the images within the slider are not properly adjusting size (I have no experience in this area) and it is cutting off the bottom of the image. They provided CSS but it does not seem to help.  The image file size is 600x900.  Below is the code that shows when I add the content block to my site, along with what they supplied.

```
<div class="is-section is-shadow-1 is-bg-white is-section-100">
    <div class="is-boxes">
        <div class="is-box is-align-left is-bg-white is-light-text is-box-5">
            <div class="is-overlay">
                <div class="is-overlay-content content-selectable" data-module="slider"     data-module-desc="Slider" data-html="###ATTRKEYpyTis13###" data-settings="###SETKEYpyTis13###" data-module-active="1"><div id="ND9kOPW" class="slider-on-box" style="width:100%;height:100%;display:none;"><div class="is-boxes slider-image" style="background-image: url('https://az659834.vo.msecnd.net/eventsairsthcusprod/production-iaslc-public/38f4fe986bfe4aa0a0408ca04fa7611f');"></div><div class="is-boxes slider-image" style="background-image: url('https://az659834.vo.msecnd.net/eventsairsthcusprod/production-iaslc-public/af0bfdc7ccef4257ad172f43bd893804');"></div></div><script>
var docReady=function(fn){var stateCheck=setInterval(function (){if(document.readyState!=="complete")return;clearInterval(stateCheck);try{fn()}catch(e){}},1);};
docReady(function() {
jQuery("#ND9kOPW").css("display","block");
jQuery("#ND9kOPW").slick({
dots: false,arrows: true,infinite: true,speed: 500,cssEase: "linear",slidesToShow: 1,autoplay: true,autoplaySpeed: 3000,fade: true,adaptiveHeight: true,responsive: [{breakpoint: 480,settings: {arrows: false,slidesToShow: 1}}]
});
});
</script></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="is-box is-bg-white is-dark-text is-align-left is-box-7">
            <div class="is-boxes">
                <div class="is-box-centered">
                    <div class="is-container is-builder container-fluid-fluid is-content-right is-content-1200" id="contentareaIFKtVWO">

    <div class="row">
  </div>
```

Tech support asked me to add this to the site, shown in context above:

````
var docReady=function(fn){var stateCheck=setInterval(function (){if(document.readyState!=="complete")return;clearInterval(stateCheck);try{fn()}catch(e){}},1);};
docReady(function() {
jQuery("#ND9kOPW").css("display","block");
jQuery("#ND9kOPW").slick({
dots: false,arrows: true,infinite: true,speed: 500,cssEase: "linear",slidesToShow: 1,autoplay: true,autoplaySpeed: 3000,fade: true,adaptiveHeight: true,responsive: [{breakpoint: 480,settings: {arrows: false,slidesToShow: 1}}]
});
});```
````